# PHP use variable to populate associative array

Tags: php

I am currently populating an associative array like this:

```
$plates_data['data'][] = array("drilldown"=>$sImageUrl, "type"=>$Type, "job_no"=>$Job_No, "customer"=>$Customer);
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$myvar = '"drilldown"=>$sImageUrl, "type"=>$Type, "job_no"=>$Job_No, "customer"=>$Customer';

 $plates_data['data'][] = array($myvar);
```

This doesn't work, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In the scenario provided your second option is just extra lines and wouldn't result in shorter code

Comment: you are adding an array that contains a single entry which is a string to the next element in the `data` element of the `$plates_data` array.

Comment: variables inside single quotes will not be expanded. also not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
$array_holder = array("drilldown"=>$sImageUrl, "type"=>$Type, "job_no"=>$Job_No,"customer"=>$Customer);

 $plates_data['data'][] = $array_holder;
```

Comment: This works, thanks so much!. I have to use the array more than once in a script. If I had to change entries, I had to do it twice, now I can do it once.

Comment: You can directly use it like this

 $plates_data['data'][] = array("drilldown"=>$sImageUrl, "type"=>$Type, "job_no"=>$Job_No,"customer"=>$Customer);